# Discrepancy between UniProt and AlphaFold data for MlaD domains – Seeking guidance on automating entry sorting based on accurate domain count

Tags: uniprot, alphafold

Hey fellow researchers,

I recently conducted an analysis on the UniProt database, specifically focusing on entries with MlaD domains. After downloading the data and opening it in an Excel file, I noticed a significant discrepancy with the AlphaFold predictions.

For instance, entry "A0A336N986" in UniProt indicates only 1 MlaD domain (link: [UniProt Entry](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/A0A336N986/entry#sequences)), but when cross-referencing with AlphaFold (link: [AlphaFold Entry](https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk/entry/A0A336N986)), it reveals 5 MlaD domains with high confidence values.

Considering the large dataset with over 100k entries, manually sorting them based on the accurate count of MlaD domains seems impractical. I'm reaching out to the community for guidance on automating this process. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have suggestions on tools, scripts, or strategies to efficiently sort UniProt entries based on the correct number of MlaD domains?

Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.